# Have problems with using Volt with phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

Seams that inheritance does not work in volt templates.

> Phalcon version is 0.6.1

Have a file structure:

- views/

  - index/

    - index.html
  - layouts/

    - main.html
- index.php

index.php:

```php
<?php
    $di = new Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();
    $di->set('volt', function ($view, $di){
        return new Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt($view, $di);
    });

    $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
    $view->setViewsDir("views/");
    $view->registerEngines(array(
        ".html" => 'volt'
    ));
    $view->setDi($di);
    $view->start();
    $view->render("index", 'index');
    $view->finish();
    echo $view->getContent();
```

views/index/index.html

```
{% extends "layouts/main.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Index</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

views/layout/main.html

```
<h1>Main</h1>
{% block content %}
    Not index
{% endblock %}
```

When I run `php index.php` I get:

> Uncaught exception 'Phalcon\Mvc\View\Exception' with message 'Template view to extend  'layouts/main.html' doesn't exists'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That comes from the fact that the application cannot find the file `main.html` in the actual path. If you add the full path it works, however it is inconvenient to do so.

Something like this will work

```
{% extends  "../views/layouts/main.html" %}
```

or if your app is under `app`

```
{% extends  "../app/views/layouts/main.html" %}
```

I believe there should be a way to either reference the root path and/or the views path directly from Volt's setup. That could very well be a NFR.

Comment: My understanding root should be views folder. As it is in Twig. So looks like a bug.